# Upgrading to 22.04. LTS

Tags: upgrade

The screen locked down when "Installing Upgrades" at 'Firefox Snap'. PC ran all night stuck. No key strokes would work. Had to shut it down by turning off the PC. Now it won't boot up. I get a "See administrator message". I never got an error message, it just froze during the "installing upgrades phase. I have upgraded many times over the years without a problem. I know very little about Ubuntu and use it only for internet research. How can Ubuntu be removed under this circumstance?

Comment: Ubuntu cannot be *removed* -- it is not an application. Like any OS, Ubuntu can be *overwritten* by the next OS that you want to control the hardware. The OS installer will handle the details for you.

Comment: research how to boot up into `recovery mode` and choose to open up a root shell in terminal ...  from there remove any nvidia driver if you are using one to have system boot up using nouveau gps driver ... at this root shell you can issue the commands to fix your boot up issue

Comment: You weren't very specific on details as to problem; you should have been able to switch to text terminal (eg., ctrl+alt+F4) even if GUI was stuck, or direct kernel to reboot using SysRq commands -- if you did need to poweroff then it's possibly a hardware issue not software (*though power spike can cause hardware to misbehave & cause software to crash but problem is still hardware related*).  I'd recommend checking hardware if you tried all keystrokes like you said.

Comment: Can you access the BIOS to change the boot priority?